# Showing that $\left (\frac{\sin x}{x} \right )^3\geq \cos^{2}x$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Show that $$\left (\frac{\sin x}{x}  \right )^3\geq \cos^{2}x,\forall x\in \left ( 0;\frac\pi2 \right )$$

---

*Firstly*, I had use the differentiation of $f(x)=\left (\frac{\sin x}{x}  \right )^3- \cos^{2}x$,but I think it very complex: $$f'(x)=3\left ( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right )^2\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}+\sin2x$$ Or I can't prove it be positive in $ \left ( 0;\frac\pi2 \right )$

*Secondly*, I had use the convex function, but function $f(x)=\left (\frac{\sin x}{x}  \right )^3-\cos^{2}x$ isn't convex or concave in all $ \left ( 0;\frac\pi2 \right )$

Comment: what's your attempt?

Comment: Please wait, I will add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the quantities involved are positive, you can shift around the terms to get an equivalent inequality:
$$\tan^2x\sin x\ge x^3\tag{i}$$
Now consider the function $f(x)=\tan^2x\sin x - x^3$.

Its derivative is $f'(x)=\tan^2 x\cos x+2\tan x \sin x\sec^2 x-3x^2=g(x)-3x^2$.

Using the AM-GM inequality on the $g(x)$, we get :
$$g(x)\ge 3\tan^2x(\sec x)^{1/3}\tag{ii}$$

From (ii) we can say that $$f'(x)\ge 3(\tan^2x(\sec x)^{1/3}-x^2)\tag{iii}$$

Finally using the inequalities $\tan x>x$ and $\sec x >1$ on (iii) we get that $f'(x)\ge0$.

Now that it is known that f(x) is an increasing function, $$f(x)>f(0)\implies \tan^2x\sin x\ge x^3$$

Answer (score 6):

It is enough to consider:
$$ f(x)= \sin^3(x)-x^3\cos^2(x) $$
and prove it is an increasing function over $I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ by studying:
$$ g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{\cos(x)} = -3x^2\cos(x)+2x^3\sin(x)+3\sin^2(x).$$
$g(x)> 0$ follows from $\frac{\sin x}{x}> 1-\frac{x^2}{6}$ and $\cos(x)< 1$ over $I$.

Comment: Not obvious why $g(x) \ge 0$

Comment: @EugenCovaci: with the last inequalities the problem boils down to checking a polynomial inequality, namely: $$x^2-\frac{x^4}{4}\geq 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Start with
$$
1-\cos(x)\ge0\tag{1}
$$
For $x\ge0$, successive integration yields
$$
x-\sin(x)\ge0\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{x^2}2-1+\cos(x)\ge0\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\frac{x^3}6-x+\sin(x)\ge0\tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}2+1-\cos(x)\ge0\tag{5}
$$
From $(4)$, we get
$$
\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\ge1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^6}{216}\tag{6}
$$
From $(5)$, we get
$$
\cos(x)\le1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}\tag{7}
$$
Subtracting $(7)$ from $(6)$ yields
$$
\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}-\cos(x)\ge\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{216}\tag{8}
$$
and for $|x|\le3$, $\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{216}\ge0$. Thus for, $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$,
$$
\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\ge\cos(x)\ge\cos^2(x)\tag{9}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We can have a stronger one which is easier:

Let $f(x)=\tan{x}\sin{x} -x^2,x\in[0,\pi/2),$

$$f'(x)>0\implies \tan{x}\sin{x}>x^2,x\in(0,\pi/2).$$

$$f'(x)=\sin{x}\dfrac{\cos^2{x}+1}{\cos^2{x}}-2x>0\iff \dfrac{\tan{x}}{x}> \dfrac{2}{\cos{x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos{x}}} $$

which is true, because:

$$\dfrac{\tan{x}}{x}>1,\cos{x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos{x}}>2 \implies \dfrac{2}{\cos{x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos{x}}}<1,\forall x\in(0,\pi/2).$$

it is trivial that

$$\dfrac{\tan{x}}{x} \cdot\tan{x}\sin{x}>x^2,x\in(0,\pi/2).$$